# how to get the while loop three different variable into the json array

Tags: php, mysql, json, sql-server

actually i try to write the program from get the ms sql data select and then selected data insert to the MySQL table.i write the program which one get the final value of the table. because insert query place out side the while loop.how do i get the all the value in to the insert query??

I think can store in the while loop execution data json array.can i retrieve the one by one?

MSSQL DB connection

```
<?php
$serverName = "servername"; //serverName\instanceName, 
portNumber (default is 1433)
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"Databasename", 
"UID"=>"username", "PWD"=>"Password");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
 /*echo "Connection established.<br />";*/
}else{
 echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
 die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

test.php

```
<?php 
require_once ('inc/MSSQL_connection.php');
//require_once ('inc/MYSQL_connection.php');


     $query ="SELECT EnrolledID,Date,Time FROM dbo.view_attendance
              ORDER BY Date,Time";                    
     $result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$query);
 if ($result == FALSE){
       die(FormatErrors(sqlsrv_errors()));
   }
 else{

      while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))  
     { 

        $emp_no = $row['EnrolledID'];
        $date  = date_format($row['Date'], 'Y-m-d');
        $time = date_format($row['Time'], 'H:i:s');
     }
       //echo $emp_no;
       $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","kelaniya");
       $query = "INSERT INTO attendancedata (EnrolledID,Date,Time) VALUES ('{$emp_no}', '{$date}', '{$time}')";
       mysqli_query($conn, $query); 

  }  
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO you can just move insert into `while` loop, why not?:

```
    <?php 
    require_once ('inc/MSSQL_connection.php');
    //require_once ('inc/MYSQL_connection.php');


    $query ="SELECT EnrolledID,Date,Time FROM dbo.view_attendance
                  ORDER BY Date,Time";                    
    $result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$query);
    if ($result == FALSE){
           die(FormatErrors(sqlsrv_errors()));
    }
    else{
          $conn_insert = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","kelaniya");
          while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))  
           { 

            $emp_no = $row['EnrolledID'];
            $date  = date_format($row['Date'], 'Y-m-d');
            $time = date_format($row['Time'], 'H:i:s');
           //echo $emp_no;

           // MySQLli

           $stmt = $conn_insert->prepare('INSERT INTO attendancedata (EnrolledID,Date,Time) VALUES (?,?,?)');
           // I insert as string as was in original question (table metadata was not given...)
           $stmt->bind_param('sss', $emp_no, $date, $time ); // 's' specifies the variable type => 'string'
           $stmt->execute();
           }
      }  
     ?>
```

Comment: can not do like that .because this not same data base type .one in mssql athoer one is my sql .

Comment: it need two kind of database connection in same file.

Comment: get the data from mssql table and try to insert into the mysql table

Comment: @Nipun Sachinda, I'm not great expert in php, I know SQL to large extent, so assumed php code is correct, and I moved other connection and renamed it to make it work as far as I assumed your code was generally working: `$conn_insert = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","kelaniya");`

Comment: In this case the mysql connection is `$conn_insert`, so both connections are active in the loop.  Although I would also recommend using a prepared statement - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: can you change answer accordingly?

Comment: @Nipun Sachinda, please try updated, I'm not sure if you needed `{}` in your original insert, in examples I saw they are not needed.

Comment: @Nipun Sachinda, I used PDO, but it need to be 'initialized' before, I better rewrite

Comment: and also need the my sql Connection

Comment: @Nipun Sachinda, I rewrote, "and also need the my sql Connection" - it was already there, I used yours

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'INTO' (T_STRING), expecting ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\temp\test.php on line 24 .Get above error bro

Comment: @ Nipun Sachinda forgot quotes ' in a hurry - updated

Comment: thank you it perfectly work .thank you very much to spend your valuable time for me.

Comment: i have send 12M record to send mssql to mysql and mssql database is daliy updated.what is the suitable should i do?

Comment: @Nipun Sachinda, I think you can write another question giving more details. I can try to help you there too if you post link as comment to this question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57720402/how-to-check-the-latest-update-data-and-only-update-date-run-in-another-query

Comment: can attention above question ?if you have free time